# Linkedin company update API behavior has been changed?

Tags: linkedin-api

Would like to know, is the company update API (https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company/{id}/updates) behavior has been changed?
Last week, this API still able to retrieve the information of a company post (not just the recent updated one, but all).
Today, I only notice the content returns from the API only recent update post/comment.
Can I know is there any notice on this API being changed? And what is the workaround for this?